# Calculate ping between two connected endpoint

Tags: ping

I have a server (S) and two connected client (A, B).
 I know both clients ping to server.
 How can i calculate both clients ping to each other without sending any packet ?

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate ping"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it reliably. It is possible that there is a shorter direct path between A and B and just adding the two ping values may overestimate the ping value between A and B.